# "Genie" animation effect in XAML

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, animation, transform

What would the XAML look like to create a Genie animation effect? Take an object of any size/shape, and "Genie" it to another Minimized location. Kind of like the OSX window minimize. Maybe even a little fancier through a smoke-like effect where the path is more switch back, instead of a simple funnel (if that makes any sense).

I'm guessing that there is some sort of Path that could be drawn, and the shape could move and transform along that path. Just a wild guess.

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

:-)

http://blog.pixelingene.com/?p=50

http://blog.pixelingene.com/?p=229

Comment: Thank you Joel --- this is EXACTLY what I needed. Oh how I wish I had your google / bing skillz. :) Thx.

Comment: Links are dead, should be https://blog.pixelingene.com/2006/09/genie-effect-the-wpf-way/ I guess?